# Bigcommerce API: How do I filter out orders that are Incomplete

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to use the API to retrieve a list of all orders that are not deleted and not incomplete. i.e. similar to the list of orders you can view on the Bigcommerce admin page. I know that I can set is_deleted flag to false to filter those, but I can't find anything similar for Incomplete orders (customers have started their purchases, but not yet checked out).

Is there any way to retrieve results for all statuses excepts a particular one e.g. status_id=!0

Or is there a way to retrieve multiple statuses? e.g. status_id=2:3:4

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is just skip over orders with that status.

You can [filter the orders by only a single status](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders#list-orders) unfortunately.